# Azure database upgrade: Foreign key is not a constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, database-project

I'm using a set of scripts to upgrade the Azure database. The scripts basically executing in the local database without any errors or warnings. But when I execute the same schema scripts in Azure SQL server database, it throws `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): 'FK_dbo.Persons_dbo.Addresses_AddressId' is not a constraint.`

I have dropped the databases and executed the same script in both local and Azure environment, local sql database works fine.

Note: I'm using database schema project to generate schema script. It has the following statement which throws the error.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Persons_dbo.Addresses_AddressId];
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK_dbo.Persons_dbo.Addresses_AddressId'
```

and check table name and **schema**

And try first nocheck

```
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Persons_dbo.Addresses_AddressId];    
  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Persons] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Persons_dbo.Addresses_AddressId];
```

Comment: TABLE_NAME : Persons, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA: dbo

Comment: and TABLE_SCHEMA?

Comment: TABLE_SCHEMA: dbo, CONSTRAINT_TYPE: FOREIGN KEY.